# Scaling Image content for :before CSS sections

Tags: html, css

```
.responsive td.head1:before {
    content: url(myimage.png )
}
```

I want to put an image into a responsive table column (I'm using this to put the column titles as rows in a similar manner described at [CSS Tricks here](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/). The difference is that my 'headings' contain images. Those images need to be rescaled to fit, and I seem to be drawing a blank using such things as background-size. So is there any way to rescale/resize the image?

*Update:* Thanks for your suggestions about using a background-image - you get bonus points if someone can tell me a way of getting an image in a :before segment with an alt/description tag for disability compliance.

Comment: Give the pseudo element a height and width and use the image as a background.

Comment: See updated answer to your question about the `alt` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Append a background image to this item, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/4rB5X/1/

```
.responsive th:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/30x30);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

th
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

To address your question with the `alt` Tag for these images:

You may indeed use `content` for an pseudo alt-tag. You can use an attribute to define the desired text. Here is an exampe:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rB5X/2/

CSS

```
/* Puts the data-img-alt value of the <th> as content */
.responsive th:nth-child(1):before {
    content: attr(data-img-alt);
}

/* Hide Text from content */
th.hide-text:before
{
  text-indent: -99999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left; 
}
```

HTML

```
<thead>
  <th class="hide-text" data-img-alt="Lalala">Test</th>
  <th>Test</th>
</thead>
```

**Update:**

Like @vogomatix pointet out, the `content` property must not be null, but at least an empty string (`content:"";` would be ok). To have a workaround, try this:

```
th:before
{
  content: "";
}

th[data-img-alt]:before
{
  content: attr(data-img-alt);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. To anyone else who is trying this, please note that some form of value for content appears to be needed for this to work, even if it is an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the class a background image and style it. Try this...

```
name{
background-image:url("url here");
background-size:80px 60px;
}
```